# Why is $]$ breaking a redefinition of \marginpar?

Tags: tex-core, marginpar

Help me understand why a `$]$` in a `\marginpar` that's been redefined like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[2][]{% always add the optional parameter, make it empty by default
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax% optional parameter empty, in most usual document calls
      \oldmarginpar[\itshape #2]{\itshape #2}%
   \else%two parameters, if some other package needs to redefine the original marginpar
      \oldmarginpar[#1]{#2}%
   \fi%
}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
A few words. \marginpar{And an ugly dangling $]$.}
\end{document}
```

breaks things, but not when the above redefinition includes

```
\oldmarginpar[{\itshape #2}]{{\itshape #2}}
```

instead.

Is there a better way to avoid this?

Comment: No, if the argument is used in the optional argument of \oldmarginpar you must protect the ] by braces to avoid that it is mistaken for the end of the optional argument.

Comment: @Ulrike Thanks. It surprises me that `$$` is not already hiding it. Can you think of any other characters that could break the new marginpar?

Comment: $ $ doesn't build a group. I don't think that there is another char. But putting braces around the optional argument is always a good idea if you don't know exactly what will be its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the optional argument, lest the the `]` is thought of as the close of the optional argument.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[2][]{% always add the optional parameter, make it empty by default
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax% optional parameter empty, in most usual document calls
      \oldmarginpar[{\itshape #2}]{\itshape #2}%
   \else%two parameters, if some other package needs to redefine the original marginpar
      \oldmarginpar[{#1}]{#2}%
   \fi%
}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
A few words. \marginpar{And an ugly dangling $]$.}


A few words. \marginpar[not an ugly duckling]{And an ugly dangling $]$.}

\clearpage
A few words. \marginpar{And an ugly dangling $]$.}


A few words. \marginpar[not an ugly duckling]{And an ugly dangling $]$.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]